# SQL Server procedure, why two input parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have this procedure, it asking me 2 input parameters, don't know why as I'm declaring the 2nd parameter (`@monto`) as an output:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MONTO_APROBADO]  
   @ID INT,  
   @MONTO INT OUTPUT  
AS  
BEGIN  
   SELECT @MONTO = MONTO_APROBADO   
   FROM LICITACION 
   WHERE COD_PROYECTO = @ID  
END
```

[image]

Any hint please?

Comment: Because you need to tell whatever it is your using where to store the value. (not sure where that dialogue is from).

Comment: @Larnu please, could you tell me how, I'm very new to sqlserver (just 1 hour...)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Just because a parameter is marked as `output`, that doesn't mean that it cannot be *supplied* a value as input which will be readable within the stored procedure.

That is, T-SQL doesn't have a concept like `inout` because all `output` parameters are effectively this.

If you don't want to supply a value, make sure the parameter can accept `null`s and then supply that as the input value.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, how could I declare it as `null`?

Answer (score 1):

Because OUTPUT parameters are actually input-output parameters

Answer (score 0):

When using a Stored procedure with an `OUTPUT` parameter, you still need to specify it when you execute the procedure.

I don't know what that image is from, however, using SQL you would need to do:

```
DECLARE @ID int, @Mondo int;
SET @ID = 1; --guessed value

EXEC SP_MONTO_APROBADO @ID, @Mondo OUTPUT;

PRINT @Mondo; --Don't know what you're doing with the OUTPUT value
```

Not specifying the second second parameter would result in a syntax error; as you aren't providing enough parameters for the SP. Regardless of if a Parameter in an input or output you still need to provide them at execution so that the Data engine knows where to get the values from, or where to store the resulting ones.

Also, it's work noting that prefixing your objects like that is a bad idea.  [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)